# Como hacer .map de un array dentro de un documento

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo el siguiente documento:

```
 Nro_Orden: '100',
 Tipo: 'Solicitud de market',
 Estado: 'Orden en espera',
 time: 2020-07-12T19:59:18.980Z,
 Lista:
      [ { _id: 5f0b6ba0d9cea95868dbea56,
          Codf: '7750182001687',
          Descr: 'Coca Cola 2.5l',
          Catd: 12 },
        { _id: 5f0b6bafd9cea95868dbea57,
          Codf: '7751580000968',
          Descr: 'Pepsi 3l',
          Catd: 6 } ],
 __v: 0 }
```

Cual seria la forma de hacer un .map del array Lista para que quede en una tabla, tengo la siguiente prueba pero no retorna nada:

```
<tbody>
      {OrdenData.map((data) => (
         <tr key={data._id}>
            <th>{data.Lista[0]._id}</th>
         </tr>
      ))}
</tbody>
```

cual seria la forma correcta de mapear un array dentro de un documento?

Answer (score 1):

Modifique mi código y solucioné mi problema: mostré todos los objetos dentro de mi array Lista en una tabla:

```
    {InfoOrden.map((data) => (
        <tbody style={{color:'white'}}>
                {data.Lista.map((dt) => (
                    <tr key={dt._id}>
                        <th>{dt.Codf}</th>
                        <th>{dt.Descr}</th>
                        <th>{dt.Catd}</th>
                        <th>
                            <button className='btn btn-danger' onClick={(e) => delItem(dt._id)}><i className="material-icons">delete</i></button>
                        </th>
                   </tr>
                ))}
    </tbody>
))}
```

Comment: entonces ya lo solucionaste? o esperabas otro resultado?

Comment: Sí, solucionado. ya lo edité para que quede claro, gracias.